# MySQL commands running in shell script possess an error

Tags: mysql, shell

I am preparing a automated shell script but MySQL commands running in shell script possess an Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure and error of .sock.
Please Help me...
My Code is:

```
user="root"
password="7layer"
db="mysql"
mysql -u "$user" -p"$password"  <<EOF
  use $db;
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
update user set Password=PASSWORD('7layer') where user='root';
UPDATE mysql.user SET password_expired='N' WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
exit;
EOF
```

The Output is:

```
Starting MySQL.                                            [  OK  ]
Shutting down MySQL..                                      [  OK  ]
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
[root@autoinstallapi AutoInstall]#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit your users `~/.my.cnf` file and add

```
[mysql]
user=root
password=7layer
```

Secure the file:

```
chmod 600 ~/.my.cnf
```

then you might need to restart mysqld (`/etc/init.d/mysqld restart`), but are able to use :

```
mysql <<EOF
use $db;
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
###your sql queries###
exit;
EOF
```

without a password

**update:**

This is not bound to your single script, it's bound to the user. If that's critical, setup a new user for the script that may access mysql without entering a password from command line.

**update:**

As you can see in your question, `Shutting down MySQL..` your MySQL server is not running. Take a look into the logs why it's aborting. One of these should contain more information:

```
/var/log/mysql.err
/var/log/mysql.log
/var/log/mysql/mysql.log
/var/log/mysql/mysql.err
```

Comment: {MySQL server PID file could not be found!                  [FAILED]
Starting MySQL..The server quit without updating PID file ([FAILED]/mysql/autoinstallapi.ril.com.pid).
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
}

Comment: Take a look into the logs. **Make sure the PID file is existent and writable by the database's uid**

Comment: You look into the pid folder (`ls -al /folder/to/mysql/pid/`) for the pid file. The path `/mysql/autoinstallapi.ril.com.pid` looks not correct. My MySQL pid file is in `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid`. You should ask this question at serverfault.com