# Where is my.cnf equivalent file on Windows

Tags: mysql, database, shell, database-backups, my.cnf

Where can I setup **"my.cnf" file** on **Windows**?
An automated backup script is running. And it is producing an on-screen message:

```
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
```

Related to: [**MySQL "my.cnf" file**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17423994/mysql-commands-running-in-shell-script-possess-an-error)

Answer (score 6):

This is an old question, but I'm providing an answer that works for current versions of MySQL (based on 5.6.21 and later).

To make passwords work you can't use any of the `my.cnf` or `my.ini` files, you must use the `%APPDATA%\MySQL\.mylogin.cnf`.  In addition, you cannot create a plain text file, you have to use the `mysql_config_editor` tool to create the file.

For example, say you want to create an automated login for your backup script. First, open a command prompt *as the user that will run the job*:

```
runas /user:jobserviceaccount@mydomain cmd
```

That will open a window running as your job account's user (and create a directory under C:\Users for it).

Next, using the new command window, run the command that will create the `.mylogin.cnf` file.  For example:

```
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysql_config_editor" set --user=root --password
```

In the above example, the tool will prompt you for the password.  Type in the password you want, and the file will be created.

Now mysql and mysqldump will use the file you just created as the credentials whenever the account you set it up under is logged in (Task Scheduler can log in a user when it runs a job).

Comment: Awesome. Only the command was enough: `mysql_config_editor set --user=root --password`. It created a non-readable file `%APPDATA%\MySQL\.mylogin.cnf` and it works.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, MySQL programs read startup options from the following files, in the specified order

- Global options (File Name)

  - %PROGRAMDATA%\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini, %PROGRAMDATA%\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.cnf
  - %WINDIR%\my.ini, %WINDIR%\my.cnf
  - C:\my.ini, C:\my.cnf
  - INSTALLDIR\my.ini, INSTALLDIR\my.cnf
- The file specified with --defaults-extra-file=path, if any

  - defaults-extra-file
- Login path options

  - %APPDATA%\MySQL.mylogin.cnf

[Official documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/option-files.html)

Comment: Not all paths works. Here, I compiled a list: WORKS c:\my.cnf
WORKS c:\my.ini
WORKS C:\xampp\mysql\my.cnf
WORKS C:\xampp\mysql\my.ini
WORKS %WINDIR%\my.ini\my.cnf
WORKS %WINDIR%\my.ini\my.ini
WORKS INSTALLDIR\my.cnf
WORKS INSTALLDIR\my.ini
WORKS mysql --defaults-extra-file=c:\my-extra.ini (any file name/extension)

NOT WORKING C:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.cnf
NOT WORKING C:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini (even after restarted MySQL, primary ini file)

Answer (score 0):

For **Windows**, **"my.ini"** is used instead of **"my.cnf"**.

**The path of "my.ini"** is as shown below in my case:

```
C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini
```